# Cant convert AnyObject(Optional) to String in Swift2

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

I am stuck on this code! I want to convert an AnyObject to String what is the best way to do that?

In this little Code-snippet below I try to convert the Result of an Realm query to String. But at the end I can't remove the Optional. Have a look:

```
print(Object)
// Print:

//Results<Subject> (
//    [0] Subject {
//        id = 10;
//        name = Englisch;
//        short = Eng;
//        mainSubject = 1;
//}

let name = Object.valueForKey("name")

print(name)
// Print:

//Optional((
//    Englisch
//))

let newname = name as! String
// Here I try to convert the AnyObject from above to a Swift-String but this don't work!
// Error: Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x7fff7db48c18) to 'NSString' (0x7fff7e4ed268).

print(newname)
// Will never be executed
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
let name = Object.valueForKey("name") as! [String]
let newName = name.first!
print(newName)
```

This is not elegant but it works ;-)

and sorry that I can't vote yet. But when I've earned 15 reputation, my votes will become public

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let name = Object.valueForKey("name").stringValue!

print(name) //Should print: Englisch
```

Don't know whether this will work for you or not. But it should, I guess.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. I get the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. And when i fix this error by adding a ! after ("name") I get the same error as runtime error

Comment: Ok and what it gives if you just print `Object.valueForKey("name")!` ?

Comment: Thank you @iReadMe . I had a similar issue. But with your comment. I took let mess2 = json[index]["Messages"][1].string! to just let mess2 = json[index]["Messages"][1] and now instead of getting a nil I get null and it unwraps the optional!! And my code never crashes now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the name property is of type `NSMutableArray` (`__NSArrayM` in the error message) so you should cast it to `[String]`.